# Unable to install gitlab on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, passwords

I'm new to Ubuntu and try to install gitlab(also new to gitlab :) ) on it. Getting the following error:

> PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
> "git"  FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "git"

Couldn't progress unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

What installation type are you using for installing GitLab. If you are new to GitLab and ubuntu, then I recommend following the instructions mentioned [here](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu)

The error message `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user 'git'` typically occurs when attempting to establish a connection to a PostgreSQL database and the authentication process for the specified user 'git' has failed. This error often arises in the context of Ruby on Rails applications that use PostgreSQL as the database.